# clang++ 2d array pointer weird errors

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

The following code compiles fine with g++, but fails with clang++ in c++11 mode. I have noted the errors inline. Can some one explain exactly what the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int nx=1000;
    int ny=1000;
    double *p=new double[nx*ny];
    auto pp=(double (*)[nx])p;//fine
    auto pp2=(double (*)[nx])p;//fine
    pp=pp2;  //error: assigning to 'double (*)[nx]' from incompatible type 'double (*)[nx]'
    decltype(pp2) pp3=pp2;//fine
    double (*pp4)[nx]=(double(*)[nx])p;//error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'double (*)[nx]' with an rvalue of type 'double (*)[nx]'
    double (*pp5)[nx]=pp;//error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'double (*)[nx]' with an lvalue of type 'double (*)[nx]'
    pp=pp2;//error: assigning to 'double (*)[nx]' from incompatible type 'double (*)[nx]'
    pp=(double(*)[nx])p;//error: assigning to 'double (*)[nx]' from incompatible type 'double (*)[nx]'
    pp[1][0]=1;
    cout << pp2[1][0]<< endl;
}
```

Comment: This is about a gcc extension: variable length arrays (also present in C99). Compile with warnings and `-pedantic` and `-std=c++11`.

Comment: `//fine` would be a relative term on both of those those initial decls (`pp` and `pp2`), as they both expect your C++ implementation to support non-standard variable-length arrays, and clang should be at-least warning you about said-same in addition to spewing the errors you're posting. (my 3.5 toolchain certainly does).

Comment: I am using clang 3.5svn in mac 10.10. Any idea why it takes some lines but not the other lines?